# Journey Builder - Engagement split based on who clicked on what content block

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

do you you if it is possible to create a journey with engagement split based on who clicked on what content block and those who didn't click on specific content block in email go into another path?

Comment: Are the content blocks clickable? What type of content blocks do you reference?

Comment: @RachidMamai currently I'm doing just a research. So if there will be button inside this content block we will be able to do such split?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm answering here for more visibility.

Currently, Engagement Split works only with static links. So yeah, if your button redirects to a static URL, you can use Engagement Split without any problem.

But if you need to use dynamic links (links containing personalization strings or AMPScript), you need some custom actions. I've written an article on how to use Engagement Split with dynamic links here:

https://sfmcify.com/docs/SFMC%20Builders/DynamicLinksInJourneyBuilder

For your information, an Idea Exchange has been created to ask for dynamic links monitoring enablement in Engagement Splits.

https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GditdUAB/engagement-split-click-enable-dynamic-links-to-be-monitored

Comment: Thanks a lot for your feedback. I will check that :)

Comment: No worries ^^ Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: @Natalia FYI, you need to click the check mark below the downvote icon to accept the answer ;)

Comment: Sorry I'm new here :D I don't see any icon like that..

Comment: I've found it! thanks! :)